# Font animation partially working

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I am new to programming and am having some issues with my animation.
The issue isI can only get my "Treats"  to move but not the "Tricks". Any advice would be greatly appreciated...I may have gotten a bit over my head. :)

```css
section {
  width: 900px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-size: 35px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #8ac30c;
  text-shadow: 3px 3px 0 #4c004c, -1px 1px 0.5em #4c004c, 1px -1px 0.5em #4c004c, -2px -2px 0 #4c004c;
}
section ul {
  list-style: none;
}
.tricks {
  float: left;
}
.treats {
  float: right;
}
/*text animation*/

.moving {
  font-size: 70px;
  animation: move 8s infinite;
}
@keyframes move {
  from {
    margin: 50px;
  }
  5% {
    transform: rotate(10deg);
  }
  25% {
    margin-right: 30px;
  }
  45% {
    margin-right: 50px;
  }
  60% {
    margin-left: 160px;
    transform: rotate(-10deg);
  }
  75% {
    margin-left: 160px;
  }
  to {
    margin: 50px;
  }
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="tricks">
    <h1 class="moving">Tricks</h1>
    <ul>
      <li>Ghoslty Musical Chairs</li>
      <li>Pin the Tail on the Black Cat</li>
      <li>Mummy Wrap</li>
      <li>Bob for Apples</li>
      <li>Carve Jack-O-Lanterns</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="treats">
    <h1 class="moving">Treats</h1>
    <ul>
      <li>Chocolate Mice</li>
      <li>Spider Cider</li>
      <li>Caramel Apples</li>
      <li>Mud and Worms</li>
      <li>Monster Eyes</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
.treats {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
}

.tricks {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
}

section ul {
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```